# How can I prevent ResponseInterceptors from executing when using a RequestErrorInterceptor in Ballerina?

Tags: rest, http, request, interceptor, ballerina

I'm looking to implement a `RequestErrorInterceptor` to handle errors occurring in Ballerina HTTP request interceptors.

Within this error interceptor, I aim to generate an error response message and prevent any further processing. Here's the RequestErrorInterceptor code I've written:

```php
public isolated service class FhirRequestErrorInterceptor {
    http:RequestErrorInterceptor;

    resource isolated function 'default [string... path](http:RequestContext ctx, http:Caller caller, 
                                                        http:Request req, error err) returns http:InternalServerError {
        log:printError("HIT FhirRequestErrorInterceptor");
        http:InternalServerError errorResponse = {
            body: "FhirRequestErrorInterceptor response"
        };

        return errorResponse;
    }
}
```

However, I've noticed that ResponseInterceptors are also being executed. How can I achieve my requirement without invoking Response interceptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of execution in Ballerina depends on how you've configured the interceptor pipeline. If you return a valid HTTP response from your `fhirRequestErrorInterceptor`, it will trigger any subsequent response interceptors in the pipeline.

Consider the following pipeline setup as an example:

interceptors: [`RequestInterceptor`, `ResponseInterceptor1`, `RequestErrorInterceptor`, `ResponseInterceptor2`]

In this setup, if your `RequestInterceptor` returns an error and your `RequestErrorInterceptor` returns an HTTP response, the following sequence of events will occur:

1. The request passes through the `RequestInterceptor`, resulting in an error.
2. The error is intercepted by the `RequestErrorInterceptor`, which generates a valid HTTP response.
3. As a valid response is returned, the control shifts to the response flow, and any response interceptors downstream in the pipeline are triggered.
4. Consequently, the response will be processed by `ResponseInterceptor1`.

If we want to prevent `ResponseInterceptor1` from being executed in this scenario, you can simply rearrange the interceptor pipeline by placing `ResponseInterceptor1` after `RequestErrorInterceptor`, like this:

interceptors: [`RequestInterceptor`, `RequestErrorInterceptor`, `ResponseInterceptor1`, `ResponseInterceptor2`]

This adjustment in the pipeline order will ensure that `ResponseInterceptor1` is only triggered when a valid request passes through and is not invoked when the `RequestErrorInterceptor` handles errors.